# 400 Bad Request not going through custom exception handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

This 400 Bad Request does not go through my exception handler:

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'subscriptionId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get(System.Guid)' in 'Product.Controllers.ItemController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

On my `WebApiConfig.cs` I have this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new HttpExceptionHandler());
```

Every exception thrown from Action, Repository, Service Layer levels are handled by this exception handler. But for this error , the generic WebApi exception handler kicks in.

How should I fix this in order for this exception to go through my exception handler?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, here my solution

1- Add a filter

```
public class RequestNoValidoAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                RequestMessage = actionContext.Request,
                Content = new StringContent("Formato no válido.")
            };
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
}
```

2- Add the filter in your `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Filters.Add(new RequestNoValidoAttribute());
```